# Reference character quiz question and choices from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

My quiz is currently working But has reached a point where there is too much HTML. I was looking for a way to reference my questions and choices from the script.js. After looking online most ways it's been done it has a variable with the question, choices, and correct answer, however, my quiz does not have a right/wrong answer to it. Rather its purpose is to show which is the user's character class is after answering questions e.g. like a personality quiz.

Here is part of the code:

```
<main id="quiz-container">
    <img src="/assets/images/imgbin_destiny-jigsaw-puzzles-puzzle-video-game-png.png" alt="">
    <div id="intro">
        <button id="beginquiz">Start the quiz</button>
    </div>
  
    <div class="question" id="q1" data-next="q2">
        <h2>Question 1:</h2>
        <p>How would you prefer to get around? </p>
        <div class="choices">
            <button class="btn" data-score="Hunter">Double Jump</button>
            <button class="btn" data-score="Warlock">Float</button>
            <button class="btn" data-score="Titan">Jetpack</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="question" id="q2" data-next="q3">
        <h2>Question 2:</h2>
        <p>What ability would you choose? </p>
        <div class="choices">
            <button class="btn" data-score="Titan">Barricade</button>
            <button class="btn" data-score="Warlock">Rift</button>
            <button class="btn" data-score="Hunter">Dodge</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="question" id="q3" data-next="q4">
        <h2>Question 3:</h2>
        <p>What title appeals to you?</p>
        <div class="choices">
            <button class="btn" data-score="Warlock">Space magician </button>
            <button class="btn" data-score="Titan">Absolute tank/unit</button>
            <button class="btn" data-score="Hunter">Stealth gunslinger</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="question" id="q4" data-next="q5">
        <h2>Question 4:</h2>
        <p>Arc What super/alt sounds interesting to you?</p>
        <div class="choices">
            <button class="btn" data-score="Hunter">Staff wielder</button>
            <button class="btn" data-score="Titan">Thunder fists</button>
            <button class="btn" data-score="Warlock">Electric beam/fingers</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="question" id="q5" data-next="q6">
        <h2>Question 5:</h2>
        <p>Solar What super/alt sounds interesting to you?</p>
        <div class="choices">
            <button class="btn" data-score="Titan">Hammer time</li>
            <button class="btn" data-score="Warlock">Flame blade</li>
            <button class="btn" data-score="Hunter">Golden gun</li>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="question" id="q6" data-next="q7">
        <h2>Question 6:</h2>
        <p>Void What super/alt sounds interesting to you?</p>
        <div class="choices">
            <button class="btn" data-score="Warlock">Space energy ball</button>
            <button class="btn" data-score="Hunter">Elusive archer</button>
            <button class="btn" data-score="Titan">Shield defence</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="question" id="q7" data-next="q8">
        <h2>Question 7:</h2>
        <p>Melee preference?</p>
        <div class="choices">
            <button class="btn" data-score="Titan">Punchy boi</button>
            <button class="btn" data-score="Hunter">Knife to meet you</button>
            <button class="btn" data-score="Warlock">open palm slap</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="question" id="q8" data-next="result">
        <h2>Question 8:</h2>
        <p>What play style appeals to you?</p>
        <div class="choices">
            <button class="btn" data-score="Titan">Tank</button>
            <button class="btn" data-score="Hunter">Mobility</button>
            <button class="btn" data-score="Hunter">Ability</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="result">
        <h2>Class Results</h2>
    </div>
</main>
```

```
#quiz-container {
    width: 80%;
    border: 1pz grey solid;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px;
    display: grid;
}

#quiz-container img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 30%;
}

.question, #result {
    display: none;
}

.choices {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.btn {
    border: 2px solid;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
}

.btn:hover {
    border-color: black;
}

#intro, .question, #result {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#beginquiz {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0.5em;
    width: 20em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#beginquiz:hover {
    color: #bfbfbf;
    background-color: #555;
}
```

```
// Create a listener for clicks on the 'start the quiz' button on the front page. 
document.getElementById("beginquiz").addEventListener("click", startQuiz);

// When the button is clicked the 'intro' div is hidden and the first question div is displayed
function startQuiz () {
    document.getElementById("intro").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("q1").style.display = "block";
}

// Create an array object to store all the quiz answers. Each selected answer should increase the category score by 1. The highest score will be the personality 'type' in the results. 
const answerData = { // one object, with names as keys, scores as values
    Warlock: 0,
    Hunter: 0,
    Titan: 0
};

// Get all of the .choices elements
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".choices");
// Add an onclick event listener to every element with a class of .choices
for (var i = 0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++) {
    // When an element with .choices is clicked, run the function called buttonClicked
    buttons[i].onclick = buttonClicked;
    }

// Define what buttonClicked does
function buttonClicked(e) {
    var target = e.target; // 1. `this` is parent, need target
    console.log(target);
    // Get the current element's data-score value
    var selectedType = target.dataset.score;   // 2. score is the value
    // Increase the selected answer's 'type' by 1
    console.log(selectedType);
    answerData[selectedType]++;  // 4. after change of structure
    // Hide the current question div
    this.parentElement.style.display = "none";
    // Work out what the next question div is
    var nextQuestion = this.parentElement.dataset.next;
    // Display the next question element
    document.getElementById(nextQuestion).style.display = "block";
    if (nextQuestion === 'result') endQuiz()
  }

  function endQuiz() {
  
    let myTypes = Object.keys(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(answerData).reduce((b, a) => {
      if (b.length === 0) return [a]
      let bb = b[0];
      if (+a[1] > +bb[1]) b = [a];
      else if (+a[1] === +bb[1]) b.push(a)
      return b;
    }, [])))
    let result = ''
    if (myTypes.length === 1) result = 'You are a ' + myTypes[0];
    else result = 'You could either be a ' + myTypes.join(' or a ');
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
  
  }
```

The main issue is how to reference the data score with its respective values. Would also like to have the questions appear at random. Not sure if the scoring structure needs to change or if there's a simple solution that I am not seeing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this. Below is one way using vanilla Javascript, where:

1. You save your questions as a list of objects in the Javascript (the `questions` variable below) rather than as raw HTML.
2. A new variable `currQuestion` tracks which question the user is on.
3. The `updateQuestion()` function pulls the appropriate data from `question` and updates the HTML as the user moves through each question.

Note that the code below will only work properly if there are the same number of `<button>` elements in the HTML as there are choices in the Javascript object for each question. You could update this to make it more flexible by adding or subtracting `<button>` elements based on the number of choices in the Javascript.

For this type of thing, though, you should know that using a framework like [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) is a great fit and will save you a lot of hassle compared to plain Javascript if you want to make this any more complex in the future.

```js
// ----- QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS ------ //
const questions = [{
    q: "How would you prefer to get around?",
    options: [{
        score: "Hunter",
        text: "Double Jump"
      },
      {
        score: "Warlock",
        text: "Float"
      },
      {
        score: "Titan",
        text: "Jetpack"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    q: "What ability would you choose?",
    options: [{
        score: "Titan",
        text: "Barricade"
      },
      {
        score: "Warlock",
        text: "Rift"
      },
      {
        score: "Hunter",
        text: "Dodge"
      }
    ]
  }
  // add the rest of the questions here in the same format as above
];
// ------------------------------------ //


// Create a listener for clicks on the 'start the quiz' button on the front page. 
document.getElementById("beginquiz").addEventListener("click", startQuiz);

let currQuestion = 0;

// When the button is clicked the 'intro' div is hidden and the first question div is displayed
function startQuiz() {
  document.getElementById("intro").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("question").style.display = "block";
  addButtonHandlers();
  updateQuestion();
}

function addButtonHandlers() {
  // Get all of the .choices elements
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".choices .btn");
  // Add an onclick event listener to every element with a class of .choices
  for (const btn of buttons) {
    // When an element with .choices is clicked, run the function called buttonClicked
    btn.onclick = buttonClicked;
  }
}

// Create an object to store all the quiz answers. Each selected answer should increase the category score by 1. The highest score will be the personality 'type' in the results. 
const answerData = { // one object, with names as keys, scores as values
  Warlock: 0,
  Hunter: 0,
  Titan: 0
};

function updateQuestion() {
  const currQuestionObj = questions[currQuestion];
  const questionDiv = document.getElementById("question");
  questionDiv.querySelector(".question-header").innerHTML = "Question " + (currQuestion + 1).toString() + ":";
  questionDiv.querySelector(".question-text").innerHTML = currQuestionObj.q;
  const choiceButtons = questionDiv.querySelector(".choices").querySelectorAll(".btn");
  choiceButtons.forEach((btn, idx) => {
    btn.setAttribute("data-score", currQuestionObj.options[idx].score);
    btn.innerHTML = currQuestionObj.options[idx].text;
  });
}

// Define what buttonClicked does
function buttonClicked(e) {
  const target = e.target; // 1. `this` is parent, need target
  console.log("target is ", target);
  // Get the current element's data-score value
  const selectedType = target.dataset.score; // 2. score is the value
  // Increase the selected answer's 'type' by 1
  console.log("selectedType is ", selectedType);
  answerData[selectedType]++; // 4. after change of structure
  currQuestion++;
  if (currQuestion === questions.length) {
    endQuiz();
    return;
  }
  updateQuestion();
}

function endQuiz() {
  console.log("Scores were ", answerData);
  document.getElementById("question").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("result").style.display = "block";
  // sort scores in descending order and check top 2
  const sortedScores = Object.entries(answerData).sort((type1, type2) => type2[1] - type1[1]);
  myTypes = [sortedScores[0][0]];
  if (sortedScores[1][1] === sortedScores[0][1]) myTypes.push(sortedScores[1][0]);
  let result = '';
  if (myTypes.length === 1) result = 'You are a ' + myTypes[0];
  else result = 'You could either be a ' + myTypes.join(' or a ');
  document.querySelector('#result .resultText').innerHTML = result + ".";

}
```

```css
#quiz-container {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1pz grey solid;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px;
  display: grid;
}

#quiz-container img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 30%;
}

#question,
#result {
  display: none;
}

.choices {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  border-color: black;
}

#intro,
#question,
#result {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#beginquiz {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  width: 20em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#beginquiz:hover {
  color: #bfbfbf;
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<main id="quiz-container">
  <img src="/assets/images/imgbin_destiny-jigsaw-puzzles-puzzle-video-game-png.png" alt="">
  <div id="intro">
    <button id="beginquiz">Start the quiz</button>
  </div>

  <div id="question" style="display:none">
    <h2 class="question-header"></h2>
    <p class="question-text"></p>
    <div class="choices">
      <button class="btn" id="choice1"></button>
      <button class="btn" id="choice2"></button>
      <button class="btn" id="choice3"></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="result">
    <h2>Class Results</h2>
    <p class="resultText"></p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: thanks this worked great! If you could hint at how I could create a restart function that would be awesome!

Comment: Great! To restart, you would need to hide the `result` div, show the `question` div, reset the values in `answerData` to 0, set `currQuestion` to 0, then run `updateQuestion()`

Comment: would this need to go after the endQuiz function?

Comment: The order doesn't matter, but it would need to be a separate function. You also need to add a restart button that calls the new function when clicked.

Comment: So if I were to reuse the beginQuiz button. Would this function make sense? ```function restart() {
      beginQuiz.innerText = "Restart";
      document.getElementById("intro").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("result").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("question").style.display = "block";
      currentQuestion = 0;
      answerData = {
        Warlock: 0,
        Hunter: 0,
        Titan: 0
      };
      updateQuestion();
  }```

Comment: I get an error when defining the answer data  and currentQuestion as 0 when called after endQuiz

Comment: Probably because `answerData` is `const`. You can't redefine it, you need to set each field to 0 individually. Keep working at it, this kind of project is great practice!

Comment: I agree! Frustrating but in a good way. So I changed the answer data to let and now it does reset the scores. However after the last question is reached the result of the quiz wont show, only the rest button. If i make the result a style.display block the result shows but stays when the quiz resets

Comment: Im guessing there needs to be and if statement at endquiz?